# Trouble with fscanf syntax when reading files from file

Tags: c, file

I'm trying to read in data from a file in C. I'm following along with an example video my professor suggested us to watch about using fscanf to read files into memory.

But I have a problem trying to figure out how to read one string after another with a delimiter in between. In the example video he reads the string in at the end of the line and stops when he hits a '\n' character.

My fscanf is returning 1 instead of 6 as it should (I think). I believe there's something wrong with my syntax of how I read my first two strings.

Here are a few lines from my data sheet:

```
ggqavxbtdtks|foo|004042|4|3|
ebsawskolwre|foo|001977|4|2|
wthbjpvgkgvy|moo|021392|4|1|
ivftrtsdqwoj|woo|122665|4|1|
```

Here's the function that reads data into memory.

```
// Read file and import data into struct
int readData(struct Transaction record[], const char filepath[], const int max)
{
    // Declare Variables
    int amount = 0;
    char ch;

    // Declare filepointer
    FILE* fp = fopen(filepath, "r");

    if (fp != NULL)
    {
        while (amount < max && fscanf(fp, "%30[^|]%*c|%30[^|]%*c|%d|%d|%d|%c", record->title, record->ctg->category, &record->amount, &record->month, &record->day, &ch) == 6)
        {
            if (ch != '\n')
            {
                while (fgetc(fp) != '\n');
            }

            amount++;
        }

        fclose(fp);
        fp = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Cannot read file\n");
    }

    // Return number of participants
    return amount;
}
```

Also this is for a personal project, nothing for school. I am just trying to learn new things.

Comment: What is the purpose of the `%*c` formats?

Comment: @Shawn im not sure, its used in the video and it works, ive also used it in previous projects with the same kinda structs and no errors.

Comment: @Shawn if i remove the '*' i get a debug assertion failure, buffer != nullptr

Comment: @user3121023 removing what u mentioned still results in a debug assertion failure, buffer != nullptr.

Comment: @user3121023 File: minkernel\crts\ucrt\inc\corecrt_internal_stdio_input.h

Comment: @user3121023 Line:1250......buffer != nullptr......debug assertion failure

Comment: @user3121023 yes it does, this has been troubling me since last night not sure the cause.

Comment: what is the definition of: `struct Transaction`?

Comment: regarding; `printf("Cannot read file\n");`  this not necessarily true AND error messages should be output to `stderr`, AND when the error is from a C library function, should also output the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`.  Suggest calling: `perror( "fopen failed" );`  as that function performs both operations

Comment: @user3629249```struct category
{
 char category[31];
 int size;
};

struct Transaction
{
 char title[31];
 struct category* ctg;
 int ammount;
 int month;
 int day;
};```

Comment: @user3629249 i found the problem for somereason i had a pointer on ctg

Comment: given the format of the data in the input file,`ggqavxbtdtks|foo|004042|4|3|`  Suggest the format string `"%30[^|]%*c|%30[^|]%*c|%d|%d|%d|%c"`  be replaced with: `"%30[^|] | %30[^|] | %d | %d  %d |"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let’s look at the scanf pattern and the input and see what happens. Your format string is `"%30[^|]%*c|%30[^|]%*c|%d|%d|%d|%c"` and your input (first line) is `ggqavxbtdtks|foo|004042|4|3|`

The first pattern is `%30[^|]` which reads characters until it gets to a `|` or reads 29 characters. So it reads `ggqavxbtdtks` (storing it in record->title), leaving `|foo|004042|4|3|`.

The next pattern is `%*c` which reads and discards one character, leaving `foo|004042|4|3|`.

The next pattern is `|` which reads and discards a `|`, which fails (next input character is `f`), so scanf stops and returns 1 (one pattern that stored output succeeded).  The remaining input to be read is (still) `foo|004042|4|3|`.